# Connect to MySQL DataBase with Laravel 5.1 and Cloudways

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1, cloudways

I'm trying cloudways as server to deploy my Laravel application on it. Everythings seems to work, except that I can't connect to Database. When I try to authenticate, I get this error :

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '***.***.**.***' (4)`

There is my .env files :

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=ynjrzmznup
DB_USERNAME=ynjrzmznup
DB_PASSWORD=**********
```

I tried to reach it using terminal :

```
$ mysql -u ynjrzmznup -h localhost -p
```

And i got this:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2562
Server version: 5.5.46-0+deb7u1 (Debian)
```

Everything work on my local environment. I can reach every public files on the server, but when I try to authenticate, I can't because the server is unable to get data from MySQL.

Comment: is the DB_HOST in local and production server different? if so, perhaps throwing `php artisan clear-compiled` might be wise.

Comment: Just did it and it's don't work...

Comment: I got it, i did a `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: ah, perhaps it's time to move your configuration from `.env` to their `/config/*.php` files.

Comment: @ElieMorin so was your problem solved after running cache command?

Comment: @Saqib Yes, my problem it's solve.

Comment: @Tezla Thank you for the tips, I'll read about this and move my configuration.